# AlertViewController - whose view is not in the window hierarchy Issue

Tags: ios, uialertview

In the following code, I am trying to call the method handleEvent only once a particular event takes place. For this, I post a notification where the event occurs (not shown in code below) , so that the notification is observed by observer and handleEvent ( as in code below).

I want a alert viewController to pop-up and take the text entry so that I can receive it. 
But I am getting following error :

```
Warning: Attempt to present <UIAlertController: 0x7f9d1347ed90> on <MSMDemoFirstViewController: 0x7f9d1347e920> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
```

I am unable to understand although I am using singleton, I am unable to get the alertViewController properly. Any help can be of great use.

```
   #import "MSMDemoFirstViewController.h"
#import "CAMDOReporter.h"
static MSMDemoFirstViewController * instance = nil;
@interface MSMDemoFirstViewController ()

@end

@implementation MSMDemoFirstViewController

+ (MSMDemoFirstViewController *)sharedInstance {
    // Singleton implementation
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        if (instance == nil) {
            instance = [[MSMDemoFirstViewController alloc] init];
        }
    });
    return instance;
}

+(void)load{
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:[MSMDemoFirstViewController sharedInstance] selector:@selector(handleEvent:) name:EVENT_OCCURRED object:nil];
}


+(void) initialize{

}
- (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    //[[CAMDOReporter sharedInstance] startApplicationTransaction:@"DemoEventApplicationTransaction"];
   // [self showAlert];
}

-(void)showAlert{
    NSLog(@"2ew");
    NSString *title = NSLocalizedString(@"A Short Title Is Best", nil);
    NSString *message = NSLocalizedString(@"A message should be a short, complete sentence.", nil);
    NSString *cancelButtonTitle = NSLocalizedString(@"Cancel", nil);
    NSString *otherButtonTitle = NSLocalizedString(@"OK", nil);

    UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:title message:message preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

    [alertController addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler:^(UITextField *textField) {
        // If you need to customize the text field, you can do so here.
    }];

    // Create the action.
    UIAlertAction *cancelAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:cancelButtonTitle style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
        NSLog(@"The simple alert's cancel action occured.");
    }];

    UIAlertAction *otherAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:otherButtonTitle style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
        NSLog(@"The \"Text Entry\" alert's other action occured.");
    }];
    // Add the action.
    [alertController addAction:cancelAction];
    [alertController addAction:otherAction];
    [self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
}

-(void)handleEvent:(NSNotification *)note{
    NSLog(@"Handle Crash Event");
    NSDictionary *crashData  = [note userInfo];
    if(crashData !=nil){
        //Implement any UI Logic to get any response from the user. e.g. AlertView, TextFields.
        //Once the feedback is received convert it into NSString and send the data.
        // Show a text entry alert with two custom buttons.
        [[MSMDemoFirstViewController sharedInstance] showAlert];
        NSString *feedback=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"crashDetails"];
        [[CAMDOReporter sharedInstance] setCustomerFeedback:feedback];
    }
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Now the output I am getting is :

```
2015-01-21 20:17:45.762 CAMAADemo[18891:1558312] Handle Crash Event
2015-01-21 20:17:45:762 CAMAADemo[18891:1807] Posting Notification about crash
2015-01-21 20:17:45.762 CAMAADemo[18891:1558312] 2ew
2015-01-21 20:17:45.778 CAMAADemo[18891:1558312] Warning: Attempt to present <UIAlertController: 0x7ff5d2273580> on <MSMDemoFirstViewController: 0x7ff5d2204be0> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
```

This means the call is going to showAlert Method, but then though I am getting same error.

Even the following code does not help.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(handleCrashEvent:) name:CAMAA_CRASH_OCCURRED object:nil];
}
-(void)showAlert{
    NSLog(@"2ew");
    NSString *title = NSLocalizedString(@"A Short Title Is Best", nil);
    NSString *message = NSLocalizedString(@"A message should be a short, complete sentence.", nil);
    NSString *cancelButtonTitle = NSLocalizedString(@"Cancel", nil);
    NSString *otherButtonTitle = NSLocalizedString(@"OK", nil);

    UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:title message:message preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

    [alertController addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler:^(UITextField *textField) {
        // If you need to customize the text field, you can do so here.
    }];

    // Create the action.
    UIAlertAction *cancelAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:cancelButtonTitle style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
        NSLog(@"The simple alert's cancel action occured.");
    }];

    UIAlertAction *otherAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:otherButtonTitle style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
        NSLog(@"The \"Text Entry\" alert's other action occured.");
    }];
    // Add the action.
    [alertController addAction:cancelAction];
    [alertController addAction:otherAction];
    [self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
}

-(void)handleCrashEvent:(NSNotification *)note{
    NSLog(@"Handle Crash Event");
    NSDictionary *crashData  = [note userInfo];
    if(crashData !=nil){
        //Implement any UI Logic to get any response from the user. e.g. AlertView, TextFields.
        //Once the feedback is received convert it into NSString and send the data.
        // Show a text entry alert with two custom buttons.
        [self showAlert];
        NSString *feedback=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"crashDetails"];
        [[CAMDOReporter sharedInstance] setCustomerFeedback:feedback];
    }
}
```

Comment: What if you use `[instance showAlert]`?

Comment: @gabbler Your comment helps I have made changes, call does go to showAlert Method , but still I am not getting UIAlertView

Comment: The change you made in `handleEvent:` to call `showAlert` will only work if the shared instance has already been created and presented.

Comment: Explain what happens with the new set of code you aded. How doesn't it help?

Comment: Thanks rmaddy ur answer helped a lot in solving problem, my event was occuring in background thread, so i posted notification in background thread. now i am ensuring that notification posted and observed both in main thread. :) Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your code is you create a whole new view controller and present the alert from the new controller. But that controller hasn't been shown, hence the error message.

The proper way to fix this code is to show the alert from the actual presented view controller.

To do this, register the actual view controller instance as the notification handler instead of registering the class in the `load` method.

Make the following changes:

1. Eliminate the `load` method.
2. Move the call to `[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(handleEvent:) name:EVENT_OCCURRED object:nil];` to the `viewDidLoad` method.
3. Change `handleEvent:` to be an instance method.
4. Change `[[[self  alloc]init] showAlert];` to `[self showAlert];`.
5. Add a `dealloc` method and unregister the notification observer.

Comment: I am developing a product related to Crash Reporting, where registering the observer before the view is loaded is important. So I can register observer in ViewDidLoad method.

Comment: Right, that's what I said. Register the observer in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: Sorry I misspelled it I cant register observer in ViewDidLoad method. My notification gets posted even before the ViewDidLoad happens. so in my case the observer should be registered before ViewDidLoad.

Comment: You can't show the alert before the view controller has been displayed.

Comment: Now I did the changes as suggested but it does not help.